# Problem importing bootstrap templates in flask

Tags: flask, flask-bootstrap

I'm new to flask and right after starting a training I hit the wall...

There's the following project structure:

```
flask_project_directory
|
+- start.py
|
+- [templates]
   |
   +- [bootstrap]
   |  |
   |  +- base.html
   |
   +- 404.html
   +- 500.html
   +- base.html
   +- index.html
   +- user.html
```

As you see, there are two `base.html` files, both contain different source code. But let's start from the top.

`start.py`:

```py
from flask import Flask, render_template
from flask_bootstrap import Bootstrap

app = Flask(__name__)
bootstrap = Bootstrap(app)


@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')


@app.route('/user/<name>')
def user(name):
    return render_template('user.html', name=name)


@app.errorhandler(404)
def page_not_found(e):
    return render_template('404.html'), 404


@app.errorhandler(500)
def internal_server_error(e):
    return render_template('500.html'), 500


app.run(debug=True)
```

`templates/bootstrap/base.html`:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    {% block scripts %}
    {% endblock %}
    {% block head %}
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport"
          content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>{% block title %}Test-{% endblock %}-app</title>
    {% endblock %}
</head>
<body>
{% block content %}
<div class="container">
    {% block page_content %}{% endblock %}
</div>
{% endblock %}
</body>
</html>
```

`templates/base.html`:

```html
{% extends "bootstrap/base.html" %}

{% block title %}- app{% endblock %}

{% block head %}
{% endblock %}

{% block navbar %}
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse" role="navigation">
    <div class="container">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navbar</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">START</a>
    </div>
    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
        <ul class="navbar navbar-nav">
            <li><a href="/">Home Page</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
<div class="container">
    {% block page_content %}{% endblock %}
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

`index.html`:

```html
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block page_content %}
<div class="page-header">
    <h3>Hi there!</h3>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

`user.html`:

```html
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block title %}-app{% endblock %}

{% block page_content %}
<div class="page-header">
    <h3>Hi, {{ name }}!</h3>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

The problem is, although both `index.html` and `user.html` extend `templates/base.html`, the code from `templates/bootstrap/base.html` which defines the navbar and related components is nowhere to be found. Also, the `templates/base.html` can't be seen anywhere. In fact, the app processes the user name correctly if it's defined, there's a greeting if the URL points to the `index.html` page, also the 404 error gets handled correctly, but there are no `bootstrap` components loaded. Also, there's no `bootstrap` styling at all, the base font is *Times New Roman*.

Is there anything with absolute paths or so? I have to add that before splitting the code to fulfill DRY assumptions everything was working correctly. It looks like I messed up with imports but have no idea where.

Comment: Did you install `flask-bootstrap` in your virtual environment?

Comment: It was added to the project packages via PyCharm GUI. It worked before splitting into modules, so it doesn't seem to be a problem of `flask-bootstrap` itself. As you can see, the `user.html` doesn't have anything in the `<head>` section - contents should've been imported from both `base.html` sources, but the rendered page has empty `<head>`.

Answer (score 0):

As soon as you have initialized `bootstrap`, the template "bootstrap/base.html" becomes available and can be referenced from your application's templates using the `extends` keyword. This you have done.

You can have only the `templates/base.html` template. You do not need `templates/bootstrap/base.html`.

Your `templates/base.html` looks generally fine and healthy. With a few modifications, you can have the remaining features that are in `templates/bootstrap/base.html`:

```html
{% extends "bootstrap/base.html" %}

{% block title %}
    <!-- You do not need to define your meta tags here -->
    <!-- Simply add your title -->
    <title>Test</title>
{% endblock %}

{% block head %}{% endblock %}

{% block navbar %}
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse" role="navigation">
    <div class="container">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navbar</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">START</a>
    </div>
    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
        <ul class="navbar navbar-nav">
            <li><a href="/">Home Page</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
    <div class="container">
        {% block page_content %}{% endblock %}
    </div>
{% endblock %}

{% block scripts %}{% endblock %}
```

`title`, `head`, `navbar`, `content` and `scripts` blocks are implementations of `bootstrap/base.html`.

Comment: Unfortunately, editing the code in proposed way didn't solve the issue. Beside that, removing reference to `templates/bootstrap/base.html` from `templates/base.html` made the DOM elements appear on the pages but without any Bootstrap formatting, like the library was never connected.